# Git newbie: about branch in my case

Tags: git, github

If other developers in the team have two branches: **master** and **develop**, then, I join the team, and initially after I cloned the project, I have only a **master** branch, meanwhile, the other team members are continuing developing & pushing code to the **develop** branch, and they have not yet merge the code from **develop** to **master**.

I would like to join the development on **develop** branch, is it so that I should create **develop** branch on my machine first, then switch from **master** to **develop** branch by `git branch develop`, then `pull origin develop`, after that I will get the up-to-date code on **develop** branch as other developers'? or Is there anything wrong in my process?

another question is, is Git branch name case sensitive or not?

**-------------------More info in my case---------**

I do not have **develop** branch yet. I have only **master** branch currently. I cloned the project long time ago, at that time there is only **master** branch, then I join the team now. I would like now to get the up-to-date **develop** and **master** branches as other developers'

Comment: Try it?  You can create a new repository in your home directory and try out the hole thing there so there will be no risk of annoying your  team mates. I think its useful when learning git to have a toy repository to mess about on.

Answer (score 2):

1. You could do just `git checkout develop`. If the `develop` branch has been fetched from remote repository, the git will create a local branch from the remote one and will set [tracking](http://book.git-scm.com/4_tracking_branches.html) of it.
2. Branch names are files on a file system. So, on windows it's case insensitive, on linux it's sensitive.

Comment: Hi, as I said in my question, I do not have develop branch yet. I have only master branch. I cloned the project long time ago, at that time there is only master branch, then I join the team now.

Comment: You should have it as a "remote branch" if you ever did `git fetch` or `git pull` or if you cloned the repo with the branch. You could list all remote branches by `git branch -r` to see it if it's here

Comment: I just did "gir branch -r", I did not see develop branch, my result is "origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
"

Comment: Ok, after I "git fetch origin", I got "develop" branch when "git branch -r", but when "git branch", I only see "master" branch, why, isn't "git branch" suppose to list all local branch? if I did not see "develop" with the command, does it mean the fetch does not yet make the develop as my local branch?

Comment: Do `git checkout develop` now. It will create the `develop` branch based on remote `origin/develop` branch. BTW, standard way is to create a release branch, but do development on the master. Why the guys did it that way?..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the `develop` branch from your Git remote, which I assume is called `origin`, is:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout develop
```

If your version of Git is recent enough, it will tell you that you now have a "remote tracking branch" `develop`.

And yes, branch names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Or rather,

```
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

(Assume your git remote is called `origin`). So the local branch `develop` will now track the remote branch `origin/develop`.

And to list all remote branches,

```
git branch -r
```